# I have a docusign account, but how to create sandbox account for it

Tags: docusignapi, sandbox

I have docusign account, but I do not see any option to create sandbox account when logedin in docusign account. How to create that one?

Comment: Same account, which you have signed up, is known as Sandbox, there is no other Link/Procedure required. Here is the definition from Wiki "A sandbox is a testing environment that isolates untested code changes and outright experimentation from the production environment or repository, in the context of software development " Once your development is completed, you need to migrate into production environment, so make sure you should use same email address for both environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandbox accounts are freely available from the [DocuSign Developer Center](http://developers.docusign.com/). Note that the Demo environment is entirely separate from Production - the accounts won't be directly related, although you can register for a Demo account using the same email address as your Prod account if you link.

Direct link to the sandbox signup page: https://secure.docusign.com/signup/developer

Comment: is the developer sandbox account has time limit or can I use it indefinitely. I mean will it expire?

Comment: The Sandbox account itself, templates and users added it to it are indefinite. Envelopes sent from that account have a watermark and are removed from the system after 30 days.